# Convert json string into json object in mule

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

Here is the scenario, I am reading data off SQL Server and its read in a map structure. The issue is that one of the fields is a JSON string but the expected output is a JSON list/object.
Here is the source data (read inside the ESB):
**Source data:**

```
{
    price_distributor=44.000000000, 
    width=0E-12, 
    tax_status=taxable, 
    web_ref=OLG, 
    stock_qty=0E-9, 
    price_dealer=40.000000000, 
    sync_uid=11, 
    shipping_class_id=null, 
    shipping_required=true, 
    attributes=[{"parent_sku":"BBB_BBBBB","variation":1,"attid":18,"attname":"Fabric Type","attslug":"pa_fabric-type","attuid":837,"option":"Black","termid":219,"termslug":"black","termuid":854},{"parent_sku":"AAA_AAAAA","variation":1,"attid":18,"attname":"Fabric Type","attslug":"pa_fabric-type","attuid":837,"option":"Green","termid":233,"termslug":"green","termuid":853},{"parent_sku":"YYYY_YYYYY","variation":1,"attid":18,"attname":"Fabric Type","attslug":"pa_fabric-type","attuid":837,"option":"Blue","termid":232,"termslug":"blue","termuid":848},{"parent_sku":"XXXX_XXXX","variation":1,"attid":18,"attname":"Fabric Type","attslug":"pa_fabric-type","attuid":837,"option":"Red","termid":235,"termslug":"red","termuid":851}]
}
```

The field in question is attributes and its content IS NOT a json array rather its a strigified array.

**Here is the output:**

```
{
  "price_distributor": "44",
  "width": "0",
  "tax_status": "taxable",
  "web_ref": "OLG",
  "stock_qty": "0",
  "price_dealer": "40",
  "sync_uid": 11,
  "shipping_class_id": null,
  "shipping_required": true,
  "attributes": "[{\"parent_sku\":\"BBB_BBBBB\",\"variation\":1,\"attid\":18,\"attname\":\"Fabric Type\",\"attslug\":\"pa_fabric-type\",\"attuid\":837,\"option\":\"Black\",\"termid\":219,\"termslug\":\"black\",\"termuid\":854},{\"parent_sku\":\"AAA_AAAAA\",\"variation\":1,\"attid\":18,\"attname\":\"Fabric Type\",\"attslug\":\"pa_fabric-type\",\"attuid\":837,\"option\":\"Green\",\"termid\":233,\"termslug\":\"green\",\"termuid\":853},{\"parent_sku\":\"YYYY_YYYYY\",\"variation\":1,\"attid\":18,\"attname\":\"Fabric Type\",\"attslug\":\"pa_fabric-type\",\"attuid\":837,\"option\":\"Blue\",\"termid\":232,\"termslug\"

:\"blue\",\"termuid\":848},{\"parent_sku\":\"XXXX_XXXX\",\"variation\":1,\"attid\":18,\"attname\":\"Fabric Type\",\"attslug\":\"pa_fabric-type\",\"attuid\":837,\"option\":\"Red\",\"termid\":235,\"termslug\":\"red\",\"termuid\":851}]"
}
```

See the **attributes** field whereas the **intended transformation should be**:

```
{
  "price_distributor": "44",
  "width": "0",
  "tax_status": "taxable",
  "web_ref": "OLG",
  "stock_qty": "0",
  "price_dealer": "40",
  "sync_uid": 11,
  "shipping_class_id": null,
  "shipping_required": true,
  "attributes": [
      {
          "parent_sku":"BBB_BBBBB",
          "variation":1,
          "attid":18,
          "attname":"Fabric Type",
          "attslug":"pa_fabric-type",
          "attuid":837,
          "option":"Black",
          "termid":219,
          "termslug":"black",
          "termuid":854
        },
        {
            "parent_sku":"AAA_AAAAA",
            "variation":1,
            "attid":18,
            "attname":"Fabric Type",
            "attslug":"pa_fabric-type",
            "attuid":837,
            "option":"Green",
            "termid":233,
            "termslug":"green",
            "termuid":853
        },
        {
            "parent_sku":"YYYY_YYYYY",
            "variation":1,
            "attid":18,
            "attname":"Fabric Type",
            "attslug":"pa_fabric-type",
            "attuid":837,
            "option":"Blue",
            "termid":232,
            "termslug":"blue",
            "termuid":848
        },
        {
            "parent_sku":"XXXX_XXXX",
            "variation":1,
            "attid":18,
            "attname":"Fabric Type",
            "attslug":"pa_fabric-type",
            "attuid":837,
            "option":"Red",
            "termid":235,
            "termslug":"red",
            "termuid":851
        }
    ]
}
```

The dataweave transformation I used for attributes is this:

```
attributes: payload.attributes
```

I know this isn't correct but is there an operator/function that can help transform stringified json into a json object/list, something like json.parse() perhaps?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, -Sam

Answer (score 3):

This problem could be solved by using the "read" function.

You could consider using something like the following DataWeave 1.0 snippet:

```
%dw 1.0
%var content = { 
    key1: "value1", 
    attributes: "{ \"stringKey\":\"stringValue\" }"
}
%output application/json
---
read(content.attributes, "application/json")
```

Output:

```
{
  "stringKey": "stringValue"
}
```

See also the [read function in the official reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-language-introduction#read):

> The read function returns the result of parsing the content parameter
>   with the specified mimeType reader.
>
> The first argument points the content that must be read, the second is
>   the format in which to write it. A third optional argument lists
>   reader configuration properties.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the dataweave snippet for reference:

```
attributes:  (payload.attributes replace /\[|\]|[\\]|\"/ with "" splitBy "}") 
    map using(attarr = $ replace /\{|,\{/ with "" splitBy ",")
        {
            parent_sku: (attarr[0] splitBy ":")[1],
            variation: (attarr[1] splitBy ":")[1],
            attid: (attarr[2] splitBy ":")[1],
            attname: (attarr[3] splitBy ":")[1],
            attslug: (attarr[4] splitBy ":")[1],
            attuid: (attarr[5] splitBy ":")[1],
            option: (attarr[6] splitBy ":")[1]//,
            termid: (attarr[7] splitBy ":")[1],
            termslug: (attarr[8] splitBy ":")[1],
            termuid: (attarr[9] splitBy ":")[1]
        },
```

Comment: This solution is going to break as soon as the order of the keys in the "attributes" field change or there are new attributes added.